# How to split coordinates in decimal form to degrees minutes seconds XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, coordinates

```
<gml:pos>42.171035 -2.07781</gml:pos>
```

I am trying to split  and recalculate coordinates from decimal form to  degrees minutes seconds I am using xslt ... 
I am new in xslt please could you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to convert the PHP code from https://www.dougv.com/2012/03/converting-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-between-decimal-and-degrees-minutes-seconds/ to XSLT 2.0 I came up with

```
<xsl:function name="mf:decimal-to-DMS">
  <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:decimal"/>
  <xsl:param name="type" as="xs:boolean"/>
  <xsl:variable name="direction" as="xs:string"
    select="if ($type) then (if ($input gt 0) then 'N' else 'S')
            else (if ($input gt 0) then 'E' else 'W')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="degrees" select="floor(abs($input))"/>
  <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="(abs($input) - $degrees) * 3600"/>
  <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="floor($seconds div 60)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="floor($seconds - ($minutes * 60))"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$degrees, $minutes, $seconds, $direction"/>
</xsl:function>
```

so with a sample XML

```
<data>42.171035 -2.07781</data>
```

and a stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:function name="mf:decimal-to-DMS">
  <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:decimal"/>
  <xsl:param name="type" as="xs:boolean"/>
  <xsl:variable name="direction" as="xs:string"
    select="if ($type) then (if ($input gt 0) then 'N' else 'S')
            else (if ($input gt 0) then 'E' else 'W')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="degrees" select="floor(abs($input))"/>
  <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="(abs($input) - $degrees) * 3600"/>
  <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="floor($seconds div 60)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="floor($seconds - ($minutes * 60))"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$degrees, $minutes, $seconds, $direction"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="data">
  <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(., '\s+')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="latitude" select="xs:decimal($tokens[1])"/>
  <xsl:variable name="longitude" select="xs:decimal($tokens[2])"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="mf:decimal-to-DMS($latitude, true()), mf:decimal-to-DMS($longitude, false())"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is `42 10 15 N 2 4 40 W`.

Comment: You are missing a component: if the original coordinate is negative, then "S/E", else "N/W". --- P.S. I wonder if using xs:time functions wouldn't be more elegant.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I have tried to add the direction. I am currently not sure whether there is a direct way to construct an `xs:time` from that decimal input value to extract components.

Comment: I meant something like this: http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGc2 Actually, I wanted to use `hours-from-duration()` for the degrees, but unfortunately the result is mod 24.

Comment: Although you *could* do: http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGc2/1

Comment: @michael.hor257k, that looks nice, only the direction `<xsl:variable name="direction" select="if ($input lt 0) then 'S/E' else 'N/W'"/>` confuses me, as Wikipedia says "Positive latitudes are north of the equator, negative latitudes are south of the equator. Positive longitudes are east of Prime Meridian, negative longitudes are west of the Prime Meridian.". Shouldn't that be then `<xsl:variable name="direction" select="if ($input lt 0) then 'S/W' else 'N/E'"/>`?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) but I have another problem I want replace item and I would like to result <gml:pos>42 10 15 N 2 4 40 W</gml:pos> in xml form

Comment: Well write a template `<xsl:template match="gml:pos"><xsl:copy>  <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(., '\s+')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="latitude" select="xs:decimal($tokens[1])"/>
  <xsl:variable name="longitude" select="xs:decimal($tokens[2])"/><xsl:value-of select="mf:decimal-to-DMS($latitude, true()), mf:decimal-to-DMS($longitude, false())"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, you are right. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 1.0, try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="gml:pos">
    <coordinates>
        <lat>
            <xsl:call-template name="decimal-degrees-to-DMS">
                <xsl:with-param name="decimal-degrees" select="substring-before(., ' ')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </lat>       
        <lon>
            <xsl:call-template name="decimal-degrees-to-DMS">
                <xsl:with-param name="decimal-degrees" select="substring-after(., ' ')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </lon>   
    </coordinates>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="decimal-degrees-to-DMS">
    <xsl:param name="decimal-degrees"/>

    <xsl:variable name="dec" select="translate($decimal-degrees * 3600, '-', '')" />
    <xsl:variable name="deg" select="floor($dec div 3600)" />
    <xsl:variable name="min" select="floor($dec div 60) mod 60" />
    <xsl:variable name="sec" select="$dec mod 60" />

    <xsl:value-of select="$deg" />
    <xsl:text>º </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$min" />
    <xsl:text>' </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($sec, '0.00')" />
    <xsl:text>" </xsl:text>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$decimal-degrees &lt; 0">S/W</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>N/E</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>   
</xsl:template>
```

Applied to your example, the result should be:

```
<coordinates>
  <lat>42º 10' 15.73" N/E</lat>
  <lon>2º 4' 40.12" S/W</lon>
</coordinates>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) but I have another problem I want  replace item  for example <gml:pos>42º 10' 15.73" N/W 2º 4' 40.12" S/E</gml:pos>

Comment: @SimonaFrankova I don't understand the problem. Please edit your question and post your existing stylesheet (minimized to what's necessary to demonstrate the problem) and the expected output.